# Spring MVC: Cannot mapping JSP files under subfolders

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, subdirectory

I'm aware there are a bunch of topics with same issues, but after 3 days researching I couldn't solve my problem.

If anyone spot the answer somewhere else, please feel free to mark this as duplicate and lead me there.

I'm trying to map a request in my Controller and then redirect to a subfolder under my default view folder. However, I'm getting a 404 error.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <display-name>SIGCOM</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springController.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>SpringFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.com.sigcom.filter.SpringFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- 
  <listener>
    <listener-class>br.com.sigcom.listener.SpringListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  -->

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/errorHandling/errorPage.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <!-- Missing resource -->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/errorHandling/error404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

My servlet XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.sigcom.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />       
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926" />
  </beans>
```

As you see, my default views folder is WEB-INF/views. So far so good. I made a subfolder like this:

```
WEB-INF/
  |-views/
    |-admin/
      |-default.jsp
```

In my Controller, I can't access WEB-INF/views/admin/default.jsp, for I get this 404 error.

My Controller:

```
package br.com.sigcom.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller

public class SpringController { 
  @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "home", "default", "index"})
  public String redirectDefaultPage() {
    return "default";
  }

  @RequestMapping("admin")
  public String redirectAdminPage() {
    return "admin/default";
  }
}
```

I tried a lot, searched a lot, however without success. I know this must be a simple detail, but I'm exhausted. Thank you in advance!

PS.: my console:

```
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SIGCOM' did not find a matching property.
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Mar 28 2017 14:42:59 UTC
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.0.43.0
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.3
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\wtpwebapps
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\endorsed
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/bin/server;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Arquivos de programas\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl;C:\morais_san\Development\Delphi\Repository\Components\JVCL3.33\jcl;C:\morais_san\Development\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\morais_san\Development\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 982 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
mai 02, 2017 9:36:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
mai 02, 2017 9:36:25 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mai 02, 2017 9:36:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
mai 02, 2017 9:36:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springController'
mai 02, 2017 9:36:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springController': initialization started
mai 02, 2017 9:36:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:36:26 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
mai 02, 2017 9:36:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springController-servlet.xml]
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[/search],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SearchController.redirectSearchPage()
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[/admin]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SpringController.redirectAdminPage()
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[ || / || /home || /default || /index]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SpringController.redirectDefaultPage()
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:36:26 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:36:26 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springController': initialization completed in 2250 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\docs
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\docs has finished in 35 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\examples
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\examples has finished in 456 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\host-manager
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\host-manager has finished in 45 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\manager
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\manager has finished in 44 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\ROOT
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\morais_san\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\ROOT has finished in 32 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mai 02, 2017 9:36:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 5763 ms
mai 02, 2017 9:59:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/SIGCOM] has started
mai 02, 2017 9:59:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'springController'
mai 02, 2017 9:59:25 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFORMAÇÕES: Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:36:26 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springController'
```

mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springController': initialization started
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:59:27 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springController-servlet.xml]
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
    INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[/search],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SearchController.redirectSearchPage()
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
    INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[/admin]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SpringController.redirectAdminPage()
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
    INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped "{[ || / || /home || /default || /index]}" onto public java.lang.String br.com.sigcom.controller.SpringController.redirectDefaultPage()
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
    INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:59:27 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
    INFORMAÇÕES: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springController-servlet': startup date [Tue May 02 21:59:27 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFORMAÇÕES: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFORMAÇÕES: FrameworkServlet 'springController': initialization completed in 1456 ms
    mai 02, 2017 9:59:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
    INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/SIGCOM] is completed

Answer (score 0):

I've tried setup a project with the same setting you had except there is no filter, filter-mapping, error-page, listener in the web.xml and I'm able to access the access the URL without 404.

The controller is able to resolve the template as well.
Did you enter your URL correctly with the context path as well?
e.g. http://localhost:8080/**SIGCOM**/admin

Comment: There must be something wrong with your other configuration setup as creating a same project works here.

Perhaps, you can try upload the minimum package to git so that we can have a look at it?

Comment: Solved, @Chris. It was my Filter!

Answer (score 0):

I've create a new project with your code. But at last, i get the right thing. Maybe you can check you url like first floor says.

Comment: Checking again... Nope.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. As you guys runned without filter, I've commented mine and worked. Now I know what to do. Appreciate your your help, guys!